# How to obfuscate user id with random number using friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, slug, friendly-id, userid

When my new website launches there will be very few users.  Currently a user's profile page is /users/:id so in the early stages it will be /users/6, etc.  I don't want others to know how many users the website has.  I think that an long id (such as a uuid) with numbers and letters looks ugly so I would prefer it just be numbers.

How can I use friendly_id gem to create a random number slug that will also be unique?  This is also my first website so any "best practices" tips regarding user id obfuscation would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from existing project:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :email, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  def normalize_friendly_id(email)
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email)
  end

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank?
  end
end
```

You can change the MD5 to a random number using something like this:

```
SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000_000)
```

Comment: How can I make sure the random number is unique and how to handle if the generated random number has been used?

Comment: I believe `FriendlyId` handles this for you. It fallbacks to uuid when it can't generate a unique id. You may want to add `validates :slug, uniqueness: true` for explicitness.